# WPF DataGrid get selected row

Tags: wpf, wpfdatagrid

Need to do some logic based on the current row selected.  New to WPF before I would do something like this;

```
int i myDataGridView.CurrentCell.RowIndex
```

Now that is not available, what is best way to get selected row?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `DataGrid.SelectedItem` property. It gives the Selected Item on the DataGrid if `SelectionMode` is `Single`. Else `DataGrid.SelectedItems` gives the multiple selection if SelectionMode is `Extended` or Multiple

Comment: If your are setting the ItemsSource of the DataGrid to your collection, then you can find the index of the SelectedItem in that collection.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

SomeObject someObject = (SomeObject)myDataGridView.SelectedItem